# EMR Hadoop long running Job gets killed

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, sqoop, amazon-emr

I have a EMR cluster when I'm running Sqoop with one mapper for transferring a 7 millions records query as Avro files to S3. After 30 minutes(+- 5 minutes) the map task sometimes gets killed and sometimes just keep in state running(never ends), but another map task is created and changed to state running, just like replacing the previous one, and the job never ends. If I change the query to give back about 1 million records the job ends normally. Looking into the logs I only found this

```
2019-10-31 10:20:29,991 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Killing taskAttempt:attempt_1572476771816_0004_m_000000_4004 because it is running on unusable node:ip-10-0-2-41.us-east-2.compute.internal:8041
```

Can someone give a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `mapreduce.task.timeout` to `0`. As per https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml:

> The number of milliseconds before a task will be terminated if it neither reads an input, writes an output, nor updates its status string. A value of 0 disables the timeout.

I presume Sqoop doesn't let YARN know that it's still running, and so the mapper gets killed.

Comment: I set this property with higher numbers and with zero, and the job gets killed as before :(